# Rendering simple text with Swift Express

Tags: linux, swift, web, swift2, swiftexpress

Does anybody know how to render simple text (without using any template) in [Swift Express](https://github.com/crossroadlabs/Express)? I can't find that in their [documentation](https://github.com/crossroadlabs/Express/blob/master/doc/index.md).

I want to have some function like this:

```
app.get("/") { (request:Request<AnyContent>)->Action<AnyContent> in
    return Action<AnyContent>.render(html: "<html><body>This is a simple html</body></html>")
}
```

And get string "This is a simple HTML" in browser (surrounded by the tags, of course)

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: This, maybe? I just discovered Express, and I'm not sure what you're asking, but it looks like it: https://github.com/crossroadlabs/Express/blob/master/Demo/main.swift#L71

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Also, they have cool [demo](http://demo.swiftexpress.io/) I hadn't found before.

Comment: Cool! And indeed nice demo.